# populate hooks with axios json response reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm having hard time on thinking how will I populate hooks with API response(json)

see below codes

```
cosnt [loginResponse, setloginResponse] = useState({
    Token: '',
    UserID: '', //from user-id
    UserName: '', //from user-userName
    firstName: '', //from user-firstName
    rcCode: '' //from attributes-rcCode 
})

const login = async () => {
    await axios.get('/API')
        .then(response => {
            console.log('response.data', response.data.resp)
        });
}
```

here's the result of `console.log`(`response.data.resp`)

```
{
    "data": {
        "token": "abcd",
            "user": {
            "id": "123456",
            "userName": "uname",
            "firstName": "FNAME",
            "lastName": "MNAME",
            "email": "email@email.com",
            "attributes": {
                "favorites": ["FAV"],
                "rcCode": ["123"]
            },
            "requiredActions": [],
            "roles": ["ROLE"]
        },
        "modulePermissions": []
    }
}
```

for `console.log`(`response.data`):

```
"resp": {
    "data": {
        "token": "abcd",
        "user": {
            "id": "123456",
            "userName": "uname",
            "firstName": "FNAME",
            "lastName": "MNAME",
            "email": "email@email.com",
            "attributes": {
                "favorites": ["FAV"],
                "rcCode": ["123"]
            },
            "requiredActions": [],
            "roles": ["ROLE"]
        },
        "modulePermissions": []
    }
},
"success": true
```

I want to populate my hooks with those datas for me to utilize it on my page.

I got `undefined` if I tried to `console.log`(`response.data.resp.data`)

On `console.log(response)`, I got:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: When you post code, validate it first.

Comment: Hi @zhulien, are you referring to the format? My apologies, I will make it more formatted next time.

Comment: No, neither your response json nor the function that did the request were valid.

Comment: hi @zhulien, can you help me with my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `async/await` and `.then()` together. Use either of those.

```
const login = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get('/API');
    const parsedData = JSON.parse(response.data.resp);
    const userData = parsedData.data;

    setLoginResponse({
        Token: userData.token,
        UserID: userData.user.id,
        UserName: userData.user.userName,
        firstName: userData.user.firstName,
        rcCode: userData.user.attributes.rcCode
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi Sir i tried and put console.log before setLoginresponse but I got `undefined`

Comment: Hi @rajiv-punjabi, I got this error `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'token' of undefined`. I also tried to console.log the userData, but I got `undefined`

Comment: Are you sure you are getting a proper response from backend services? Based on your demo data it works properly. [Playground Demo](https://jsbin.com/fakaduxitu/edit?js,console)

Comment: Hi @rajiv-punjabi, I updated my question with the screenshot of `console.log(response)` . THank you

Comment: Remove const userData line and replace with this. `const parsedData = JSON.parse(yourResponse.resp.data);
const userData = parsedData.data;`

Comment: I see. I review again the response and it is a string. Thank you. Can you update your anwer. So I can tagged it as the correct answer? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In the .then

```
setLoginResponse({...loginResponse, Token: response.data.resp.data.token, UserId: response.data.resp.data.user.id, ...}
```

You can destructure your response object first and store values in variables to make the setLoginResponse more easy to read.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: Hi @alaric, upon console.log I can't access response.data.resp.data. And for response.data.resp.data.token i got error `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'token' of undefined`

Comment: @Rymrk , you are trying to access this value in .then right ?
Just try to log your resp and check if there is data inside or another object, maybe you have typo in your api or forgot something and remove the useless async await

Comment: Hi @alaric, I stated the return of console.log above.

Comment: Check Rajiv Punjabi response above, I haven't noticed the async/await sorry about that, you can't mix both in your case,  use promise or async await as you prefer

Comment: Can you edit your post with your correct login function please ?

Comment: Hi,I updated my question with the screenshot of `console.log(response)` . THank you

Comment: You have an issue with your login function as we told you before
`const login = () => {
   axios.get('/API')
        .then(response => {
            // here: setLoginresponse(....)
            console.log('response.data', response.data.resp)
        });
}`